# How to put 2 divs next to each other without the float method

Tags: css, html, inline

I have three image divs in line with each other and above it I have a name div for 2 of the pictures. I need the names to be centered above each of the left and right pictures and because the titles differ in length, I can't use margins because obviously different title lengths require different margins to center.  I tried the `display: inline-block` command but it didn't work quite right.  For visual see below:

```
    Title               Title
---Picture---Picture---Picture---
```

Comment: Maybe you should use a table instead?

Comment: Why _without the float method_???

Comment: Use Table. That'll do

Comment: _"How to put 2 divs next to each other"_ But they're not next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it: JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rw8CF/

**HTML**

```
<table>
 <tr>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th></th>
     <th>Title</th>

 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>Image 1</td>
      <td>Image 2</td>
      <td>Image 3</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple way is to do using flex box...but it supports 
Chrome 29+ unprefixed
IE 11+ unprefixed
Opera 14+ prefixed
Chrome 21+ prefixed
Safari 6.1+ prefixed
Firefox 23+ full support soon

```
.flex-container {
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -moz-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
-moz-flex-flow: row wrap;
flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
-webkit-flex: 1 auto;
-moz-flex: 1 auto;
flex: 1 auto;
min-height:250px;
background-color:#0FF;
border:1px solid #ccc;}
```